# Using recursive generators to traverse and filter

Tags: javascript, typescript, generator, yield

I'm writing a game in typescript and I have a few recursive generators that essentially run map operations on game objects.

I want to avoid creating arrays for the game objects, since there can be upwards of a few thousand objects inside the view.

Here's a few samples of the code so you can understand the basic structure.

```
    *getBoxOverlappingValues(box: BoundingBox): Generator<V, void, void> {
        const nodesGenerator = this.tree.getOverlappingNodes(box);

        for (const node of nodesGenerator) {
            if (node.value === undefined) {
                throw new Error('Overlapping node does not contain a value');
            }

            yield node.value;
        }
    }
```

```
    getOverlappingObjects(box: BoundingBox): Generator<number, void, void> {
        return this.boundingBoxRepository.getBoxOverlappingValues(box);
    }
```

```
        const viewableObjectIds = this.collisionService.getOverlappingObjects(box);
        const viewableObjects = this.gameObjectService.getMultipleObjects(viewableObjectIds);
```

The issue is that, in my renderer service, I need to pass over the objects multiple times, and render what is supposed to be rendered on each pass.
This means that I need to filter the objects and render them at the same time.

```
    *renderObjectsPrepare(objects: Iterable<GameObject>): Generator<GameObject, void, void> {
        for (const object of objects) {
            const renderer = this.getObjectRenderer(object);
            renderer.update(this.scale);
            if (renderer.isRenderable()) {
                yield object;
            }
        }
    }

    *renderObjectsPass(objects: Iterable<GameObject>, pass: number): Generator<GameObject, void, void> {
        for (const object of objects) {
            const renderer = this.getObjectRenderer(object);
            const objectRelativeX = Math.floor(object.position.x) - this.canvasX;
            const objectRelativeY = Math.floor(object.position.y) - this.canvasY;
            const objectDrawX = objectRelativeX * this.scale;
            const objectDrawY = objectRelativeY * this.scale;
            const moreToRender = renderer.renderPass(this.context, pass,
                objectDrawX, objectDrawY, this.showInvisible);
            if (moreToRender) {
                yield object;
            }
        }
    }

    renderObjectsOver(objects: Iterable<GameObject>): void {
        let renderObjects = this.renderObjectsPrepare(objects);
        for (let pass = 0; pass < RenderPass.MAX; pass++) {
            renderObjects = this.renderObjectsPass(renderObjects, pass);
        }

        let renderObject = renderObjects.next();
        while (!renderObject.done) {
            renderObject = renderObjects.next();
        }
    }
```

This obviously renders my objects in a DFS way, so the passes don't actually have any effect.
If I consume the generator after each iteration of the for loop, the iterable is completed so I don't have any other objects left for the next iteration.

Is there any way I could make this work without allocating any arrays?

Comment: Create a new iterator for each pass?

Comment: I can't, because of the way the code is structured. Also, that would mean iterating all the objects more than one time.